# How to store a const char* to a char*?

Tags: c++, char, constants, type-conversion

I have [this code](http://cpp.sh/85hb) that works as expected:

```
#define MAX_PARAM_NAME_LEN 32

const char* GetName()
{
    return "Test text";
}

int main()
{
    char name[MAX_PARAM_NAME_LEN];
    strcpy(name, GetName());    

    cout << "result: " << name << endl;
}
```

If I'd like to store the result to a `char *` (because some functions within a Frameworks I'm using use only `char *` as input) without using the `strcpy` (for practicality and readability of code, and learning too), how could I do? Keeping in `const`, this works well:

```
const char* name;
name = GetName();
```

but I still have `const`.

Trying to just use `char*`:

```
char* name;
name = GetName();
```

I get `invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'`. What's the best habit for this kind of conversion?

Comment: What you want to do? If you do not want to change the string, the first idiom serves you and does not use extra memory; if you want to change the string you need to copy its contents elsewhere (so you need strcpy or similar).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`return "Test text";` returns a pointer to a *read-only* string *literal*.

If you're using a function that takes a `char*` as an input, and you have a `const char*` (such as a read-only string literal), then you ought to supply a deep copy of the string starting at that `const char*` to such functions.

Else you risk undefined behaviour at runtime if a function attempts to modify a read-only string.

What you currently have is adequate; assuming you can't work with `std::string`. (If you *can* work with `std::string` *and* all your framework functions take a `const char*` input, then I'd suggest your refactoring your code to use a `std::string`, and pass the output of the `c_str()` method on that string class to your framework functions.)

Finally, if some of your framework functions require a `char*` then you could always build yourself a small adapter class:

```
class Adapter
{
public:
    Adapter(const& Adapter) = delete; /*don't try to copy me please*/
    Adapter& operator=(const Adapter& ) = delete; /*don't try to copy me please*/
    Adapter(const char* s) : m_s(::strdup(s))
    {
    }
    ~Adapter() /*free memory on destruction*/
    {
        ::free(m_s); /*use free to release strdup memory*/
    }
    operator char*() /*implicit cast to char* */
    {
        return m_s;
    }
private:
    char* m_s;
};
```

Then for a function `void foo(char* c)`, you can call `foo(Adapter("Hello"/*or any const char* */));` and `foo` can do as it pleases with the `char*` that's embedded in the anonymous temporary! You could even enhance this class to take a constructor to a `char*` where in that case only a shallow copy of the pointer is taken (and the destructor doesn't delete the memory).

Comment: What if I want to "copy" the `const char*` content to a `char*` (so, without specify fixed size)? I don't know the size of that char*, since later I'll concat other char.

Comment: Oh wait. I see I can use `char* name;` and than `strcpy(name, GetName());` as well. Basically, I got a non-length-definite string, which will serve my task. Is it correct doing so?

Comment: @paizza No. Use something like `std::string name = GetName();` then pass `name.c_str()` to any framework function that expects a `const char*`.

Comment: There's also [strdup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) to create a copy of a string. You'll need to free the memory later, though, so it's far easier to use `std::string` in C++.

Comment: You need to write `name.c_str()`. `c_str` is a *function*.

Comment: `string` looks good, but I need `char *` later, not `const char*` :( .`c_str()` return const. I think I cannot pass a `string` to a `char* ` right?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need a `char*` later?

Comment: The only way is to define a fixed size (guessing it is enough) and use strcpy. That's risky, I can get access memory violation if the char* grown more than the size I've set :(

Comment: @Bathsheba: as I said, the function used by the Framework taks `char*` as input, I can't change them!

Comment: @paizza in your question, you say *some functions within a Frameworks I'm using use **`const char *`** as input*

Comment: @user2079303: I wrong, sorry! I updated the question. I need char*

Comment: OK; consider using something on the lines of the class I give in the answer.

Answer (score 16):

The best habit for this kind of conversion is to use `std::string` throughout your code. Since the framework that you are using takes `const char*` as its input, you can always pass it the results of [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) call on your `std::string`:

```
std::string GetName() {
    return "Test text";
}

int main() {
    std::string name = GetName();
    int res = external_framework_function(name.c_str());
    cout << "result: " << res << " for " << name << endl;
}
```

A distant second best is using `const char*` in your code:

```
const char* name = GetName();
```

Since the framework that you are using takes `const char*` you are good here as well.

If you need a non-const pointer, there is no way around copying the string. You can make a function that does it for you, but you would remain responsible for freeing the copies that you get from it:

```
char* copy(const char* orig) {
    char *res = new char[strlen(orig)+1];
    strcpy(res, orig);
    return res;
}
...
char *name = copy(GetName());
...
delete[] name;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the typical way to "drop `const`" is by using `const_cast<>`:

```
char *name = const_cast<char*>(GetName());
```

This is, of course, frowned upon, ugly and potentially dangerous, since it's really possible that `GetName()` returns a pointer to something that *shouldn't be changed*, and then you go and give yourself permission to change it. It's a good way to get very hard to find bugs, in that case.

A workaround is to use a `std::string` as a temporary holding area; it will mean copying the string but that might be acceptable performance-wise:

```
std::string s(GetName());
char *name = s.c_str();
```

This will of course only work if `name` isn't kept around when `s` goes out of scope. If that is the case, then you're going to have some form of persistent string storage layer.

Comment: Isn't removing const from a `const char*` undefined behavior?

Comment: If I may ask, why are you suggesting something that is frowned upon, without giving other suggestions?

Comment: @Default Because that was what the poster wanted to know how to do, and I can't know for certain that it will be bad in the situation in question.

Comment: `.c_str()` is const. `char *name = s.c_str();` isn't compilable.

Comment: @Default removing const is not UB. But you're correct that `std::string::c_str` won't work because it returns `const  char*`.

Comment: Attepting to modify characters in a C++ string literal is UB. They're typically stored in a read-only section of memory. Casting away the const won't cause the problem, but a subsequent attempt to write to that memory region will. Don't suggest such things; the only way to correctly make a mutable string from a C++ string literal is to copy it.

Comment: All these years later, +1 for actually answering the question instead of saying "don't do that."

Answer (score -2):

You could explicitly cast it. `(char*) getName()`. But you probably shouldn't. Because the `const` bit means something like "promise not to change it". So if i have a function `void foo(const char* string)` I am saiying: "give me a pointer to a string. I won't change it." 
And if you declare a variable `const char* string = "hello";` You are saying, this string should not be changed. And because you make this promise, the compiler knows, and can make your code more efficient. This is why:

```
const char* a = "hello";
const char* b = "hello";
(a==b); //is probably true
```

your compiler knows you won't change `a` or `b` so it makes them point to the same address, so it only has to store one `"hello"` string. If you now go about changing `a`, `b` gets also changed, and this is not what you wanted.

So long story short, if you are absolutely sure that the function your calling does not change the string, you can explicitly cast it. (or better, change the function to `(const char*)` if it's yours).
If your not sure, you will have to make a copy. (Like you are already doing with `strcpy()`).

Comment: Why are you suggesting potentially dangerous casts? The only correct way to obtain a non-const C string from a C++ string literal is to copy it. Any attempt to modify the non-const casted version is UB. Please don't suggest a method that will (almost certainly) result in hard-to-diagnose program behaviour down the line.